# Mouse cursor does not change appearance to indicate a program is launching

Tags: mouse, lubuntu, cursor

I am using Lubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I click on a icon to launch a program, be it from the start menu or from the panel, the mouse cursor does not change to a spinning circle (or anything else) to indicate that a program is launching. For beginners this is a very annoying problem.

I have tried to change cursor theme with `lxappearance`, using either DMZ black or white, and it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried some other cursor theme altogether? It's just possible that the two themes which are supplied by default are lightweight and don't have the feature you expect.

Comment: I just tried with the oxygen cursor theme and the cursor doesn't change with that theme either. So maybe the issue is more complex than just changing to a fancier cursor theme.

Comment: Also, for the record, note that some experienced users suggested to check .desktop file launcher and edit a line StartupNotify=true which I did for the few apps that needed and this have no effect, problem remains.

Comment: Whenever possible, please provide links.

Comment: Ant any solution for this issue? I am using Lubuntu 13.10 and I can see no way to change the mouse cursor in order to indicate a program is launching. Apart from that I find very interesting the rest of the features of Lubuntu and I really think that it could be the solution for my old computer. I have tried to change the cursor theme to oxygen too but anything change but color and size.

Comment: Anyone have a solution to this? I have noticed this on Lubuntu 16.04 LTS also. Have searched many places but no one can address.

Comment: I believe this bugfix has something to do with it. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcmanfm/+bug/1336521   It appears the problem is a missing build dependency in openbox package - libxcursor-dev. Apparently patched in latest build of Openbox 3.6.1-4 which you may need to download, build and install manually.